# Botão curtir artigo

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

tenho o seguinte botao

```
<a href='?area=ref&amp;acao=curtir&amp;noticia=$noticia->id&amp;perfil=$user'>Curtir  </a>";
```

que chama a funçao que esta na pagina action que curti o artigo relacionado, mas acontece que ao clica no botao ele redireciona para a pagina action.php e retorna para pagina de noticia como faço para apenas executar a açao que esta na pagina action.php sem redirecionar? alguém tem uma ideia

Answer (score 1):

O que você precisa para evitar q link redirecione a página é usar o `.preventDefault()`. Como o próprio nome diz "previne a ação esperada/default".

Esse código tem de ser corrido no javascript e precisa de um oscultador de eventos (event handler) que corre o código quando o clic fôr detetado e antes de o link fazer redirecionamento.

```
$('a').on('click', function(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    // resto do seu código aqui ...
})
```

Nota: no exemplo de `href` que colocou têm `->`. Presumo que esse não seja o `href` já renderizado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função para ouvir sempre que um link com a classe `.curtirAjax` for clicado.

Então seu HTML ficaria assim:

```
<a href="?area=ref&amp;acao=curtir&amp;noticia=$noticia->id&amp;perfil=$user" class="curtirBtn">Curtir</a>
```

E a função JavaScript seria a seguinte:

```
function curtirAjax(){
    $('.curtirBtn').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).attr('href'),function(retorno){
            //mensagem de sucesso aqui
        });
    }); 
}
```

E para chamar ela no seu `body`:

```
window.onload = function(){ curtirAjax() }
```

Exemplo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/DPLsB/)**